# Frac(R) problem..isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a subring of a field $F$. Further suppose that for all $x\in F$ there are $a,b \in R$ with $b$ non-zero such that $x=a/b = ab^{-1}$. Show that $F$ is isomorphic to Frac(R).

Really stuck on how to begin this problem.

Comment: Begin by writing down a homomorphism $\mathrm{Frac}(R) \to F$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: Every homomorphism from a field into a nontrivial ring is injective.

Hint 2: Can you construct a surjective ring homomorphism $F \rightarrow \operatorname{Frac}(R)$?